# xsd including variable number of elements and nested element

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm a newbie regarding xsd and xml and so I'm struggling to figure out how can solve the following problem. I have a xml file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>ECom_RU_TriggeringSearchController</members>
        <members>ECom_RU_TriggeringSearchControllerTest</members>       
        <members>Ecom_cls_UtilityCaseActions</members>
        <members>Ecom_cls_APAC_CaseActions</members>        
        <members>Ecom_NBA_cls_NBAResultsController</members>
        <members>Ecom_NBA_cls_NBAResultsController_Test</members>           
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>    

    <types>         
        <members>ECom_RU_TriggeringSearch</members>
        <name>ApexPages</name>
    </types> 

    <types>         
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types> 

    <types>         
        <members>customlabel1</members>
        <members>customlabel2</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types> 

    <types>         
        <members>StaticResource1</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>

    <types>         
        <members>Obj1</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>

    <version>29.0</version>
</Package>
```

The important thing to retain here is that i can have a variable number of `<types>` and inside each `<types>` i can have a variable number of `<members>`.
I found this xsd to represent the xml file:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Package">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="types" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="members" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="version"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My question is: despite i'm able to represent a variable number of `<types>` using the `maxOccurs` and `minOccurs` attributes, how can i, inside each `<types>`, have a variable number of `<members>`? I know i can also use those attributes (`maxOccurs` and `minOccurs`) but that the number of  inside each `<types>` varies and i need "something" that can hold a parameter which will be replace by the number of `<members>` to be used inside that specific `<types>` element.

I hope i was clear enough in my explanation...

I would appreciate any tip that can guide towards a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to have somewhere a parameter that would indicate how many members you need to describe, and check the actual number of `<member>` tags you have against this parameter?

Comment: Ideally, it will be me who's going to define that parameter. I have a function, in a bash script which will pass those two parameters, the number of <types>, which is easy, and the number of <members> for each <types>. The problem is that i don't know how to build a xsd with a variable number of <members>.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in standard XSD 1.0. In XSD 1.1 you could add assertions of the form

```
<xsd:assert test="if (name='ApexClass') then count(member)=6 else 
                  if (name='...') then count(member)= 3 else
                  if ...
                  true()"/>
```